# Domain of a section of a (pre)sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, sheaf-theory

Let $X = (X, \tau)$ be a topological space and $\mathcal{F}: \tau \to \mathbf{Rings}$ be a presheaf of rings on $X$. Since the rings $\mathcal{F}(U)$, with $U \in \tau$, are often thought as rings of functions, say $\mathcal{F}(U) = \{\phi \mid \phi: U \to R\}$, with $R \in \mathbf{Rings}$ fixed, I would like to define the domain of a section $\phi$ of $\mathcal{F}$ by setting $\mathrm{dom}\,\phi = U$, where $U$ is such that $\phi \in \mathcal{F}(U)$. But this definition makes sense only under the assumption that such a $U$ is unique. And it seems to me that this assumption is not backed up by the definition of a presheaf. So, may a section $\phi$ of a presheaf $\mathcal{F}: \tau \to \mathbf{Rings}$ belongs to $\mathcal{F}(U) \cap \mathcal{F}(V)$, for some $U,V \in \tau$ with $U \neq V$? What about a section of a sheaf?

PS: I am using the notes
http://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/~gathmann/class/alggeom-2014/main.pdf
as main reference.

Comment: You're free to define the domain of a section $\phi \in F(U)$ as being $U$ if you want. That's perfectly well-defined.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan the problem is the non-uniqueness of $U$. If there are $U,V \in \tau$, with $U \neq V$, such that $\phi \in \mathcal{F}(U) \cap \mathcal{F}(V)$, then I would have $\mathrm{dom}\,\mathcal{F} = U \neq V = \mathrm{dom}\,\mathcal{F}$, a contradiction.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by $F(U) \cap F(V)$. You should be careful to distinguish $\phi$ from its pullback in $F(U')$ along an inclusion $U' \to U$; these are not the same mathematical object.

Comment: Well, each $\mathcal{F}(U)$, with $U \in \tau$, is a ring (or the underlying set of this ring). Then $\mathcal{F}(U) \cap \mathcal{F}(V)$ is the intersection of two (underlying sets of) rings. Now, I don't know what you mean by stressing this fact about pullbacks and inclusions $U' \to U$. My question is: Is the open set $U$ associated to $\mathcal{F}(U)$ necessarily unique?

Comment: Again, I don't understand what you mean by $F(U) \cap F(V)$. There is no such thing as the intersection of two sets. (Whatever you were taught about this, it's wrong.) What is meaningful is the intersection of two subsets of a common set, but $F(U)$ and $F(V)$ are not canonically subsets of a common set.

Comment: I also, again, don't understand your second question. $F(U)$ is some set, labeled (by definition) by an open $U$. If $\phi \in F(U)$ is an element of that set, you are free to regard its domain as being $U$ if you want. That's perfectly well-defined.

Comment: "What is meaningful is the intersection of two subsets of a common set, but $\mathcal{F}(U)$ and $\mathcal{F}(V)$ are not canonically subsets of a common set."

I can not use the axiom of pair and the axiom of union (of Zermelo-Fraenkel) to consider the set $\mathcal{F}(U) \cup \mathcal{F}(V)$? Both $\mathcal{F}(U)$ and $\mathcal{F}(V)$ are subsets of $\mathcal{F}(U) \cup \mathcal{F}(V)$.

Comment: ZFC is just wrong about this. It's a meaningless operation to consider the intersection of two sets with no further context. One of the many things that will go wrong if you try to make sense of this is that $F(U) \cap F(V)$, whatever that means, will in general depend on finer information than the isomorphism type of the functor $F$, which is terrible.

Comment: Here is a question to ponder: what do you think $\mathbb{R} \cap \mathbb{Q}$ is? This is a meaningful question in ZFC, but its answer depends finely on the set-theoretic details of how you construct $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$, and depending on those details this intersection may be, for example, empty. But I think the only meaningful answer to this question, if there is one, is $\mathbb{Q}$, since $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ are both naturally subsets of, say, $\mathbb{C}$, and this is their intersection there. None of that depends on the set-theoretic details of constructions.

Comment: This last point (about the way the structures are built with sets) is one that I was posing to myself before I did that question about ZF.

Comment: Back to the main question: you are saying that the labeling of the $\mathcal{F}(U)$'s is 1-1 (with respect to the $U$'s). I am not familiar with this assumption, since I still think of functors as a kind of functions. And functions may be not 1-1.

Comment: So, I may consider each ring $\mathcal{F}(U)$ as a pair $(U, \mathcal{F}(U))$.

Comment: What I'm saying is that when you say "section," you're implicitly specifying an open set $U$ over which you want your section to live, as an element of $F(U)$. The open set $U$ is already part of the data of a section. It's already there for you to use if you want.

Comment: Yes, this is what I understood from what you said. And this is in fact an assumption I am not familiar with, since we don't think in this way when working with ordinary functions (in set theory and traditional mathematics).